# Modify PATH for gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to install a `gitlab-runner` (executor `shaell`) on my Windows 10 box. I start the job on the gitlab server and it always ends up with the message `the command "git" cannot be found` (roughly translated into english).
As a matter of fact `git` is not part of my path.
How can I modify my `PATH` variable for the shell the `gitlab-runner` starts?

To use git on the command line in windows I usually set it with the statement: `PATH %PATH%C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

Is it documented somewhere, `git` has to be available to the runner?
How can I see the command line the runner invokes (i.e. the call to git)?

Answer (score 11):

This [GitLab Runner issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1249) answers your question.

The `environment` setting doesn't work since it gets evaluated before the variables are set, but you can use `pre_build_script` in the runner config to update the path.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "My Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "Abcd1234"
  executor = "shell"
  pre_build_script = "set Path=%GIT_HOME%\\usr\\bin;%Path%"
```

Comment: Since my runner was using powershell, I had to use `pre_build_script = "$Env:PATH += \";C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\""`, but it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For testing purposes I started the `gitlab-runner` like: `gitlab-runner -l debug --debug run --config config.toml --service gitlab-runner` from the directory where the `gitlab-runner.exe` and the `config.toml` file reside.

I added the following line to the `runners` section of my `config.toml` file:

`environment = ['PATH=%PATH%;d:/java/bin;C:/Program Files/Git/bin;c:/program files (x86)/apache-ant-1.10.1/bin']`

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have the error message : "the command "git" cannot be found"...

Comment: It seems the gitlab-runner does the variable expansion using the syntax `${ENV_VAR}` even on Windows. However, it also seems that one cannot use the original value of the environment variables. So when setting `environment = ['SOME_VALUE=foo','PATH=${PATH};${SOME_VALUE}']`, I get the value `;foo` for `%PATH%`. So the variable of `SOME_VALUE` is expanded as expected but `PATH` is expanded to an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

**On macOS** the only thing that really worked for me is [this solution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3463) of adding the PATH to `Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist`:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
</dict>
```

Then restart gitlab-runner and you are good to go.

I suppose there is a Windows equivalent of this solution as well.

Comment: It seems Windows lacks this feature:  

 "The service control manager does not support passing custom environment variables to a service at startup. Also, the service control manager does not detect and pass on changes to environment variables as the service is running. Instead of making a service dependent on an environment variable, use registry values or ServiceMain arguments."

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-startup

Answer (score 0):

One can also configure the `shell` executor environment editing `$HOME/.profile` (or `$HOME.bash_profile`) of the `gitlab-runner` user.

To check the `gitlab-runner` home directory, run `$ sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep gitlab-runner | cut -d: -f6` .